# Adjusting LED brightness

Tags: arduino

I have assignment which have the following requirements:
10% Connect a button to a digital input
20% Connect a potentiometer to an analog input
20% Connect 3 LEDs of your choice to PWM outputs (place them in a row on the breadboard).
See the pin overview (Lenker til en ekstern side.) for which pins support PWM
10% Read the value of the potentiometer ten times per second
30% Use the read value to set the brighteness of the LEDs.
The lowest 1/3 sets the brightness of the first LED, the middle 1/3 sets the brightness of the second LED and the last 1/3 sets the brightness of the last LED.
Meaning: Knob fully turned off = no LEDs are on. Turn it slowly and the first LED fades in as you turn, then the second LED fades in and finally the last LED fades in.
10% Holding in the button sets all LEDs to full brightness. Releasing sets them back to the potentiometer value.

I have managed to achive the LED_1 to fade up to in 1/3 and the LED_3 to fade correct at 3/3. The problem I am stuck with, is that I can't figure out why LED 2 wont fade correct? You can see my code below with a screenshot of the circuit designed in tinkercad. I havn't written any code for the button yet. Any solutions?

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
    pinMode(A0,INPUT);
    pinMode(A1, INPUT);
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
```

}
void loop() {

```
    int value = analogRead(A1);
    int percent = ((float)value / 675) * 100;
    int percent_LED = ((float)value / 675) * 300;
    int percent_LED2 = (((float)value / 675) * 300);

    Serial.println(percent);
    if (percent < 33)
    {
            analogWrite(3, percent_LED);
            analogWrite(4, LOW);
            analogWrite(5, LOW);
        
    }

    else if(33 < percent < 66)
    
    {
            analogWrite(4, percent_LED - 100);
    }

    if (66 < percent)
    {
            analogWrite(5, percent_LED - 200);
    
    }
    else
    {analogWrite(5, LOW);}

    delay(100);
```

}

[Circuit design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA529.png)

Comment: pin 4 is not a PWM pin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using analogWrite on the pin 4. But on Arduino UNO the pin 4 does not support PWM.

PWM pins are : 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11

Check https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/ for more informations.

Comment: Oh thats it! Thanks for your help!